# Nested routing in next js

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I've looked around Stackoverflow and the general consensus seems to be adding to my server file.

Though I'm wondering if this is possible with NextJS's dynamic routing.

I'm trying to achieving a route that looks something like this:

```
/categories/:id/articles/:id
```

I've tried doing something like this

```
- pages
  - categories
    - [id]
      - :id.js
      - articles
        - :id.js
```

To no avail, so perhaps this wasn't the best approach. Would I be able to achieve something like this without touching the server?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes it can be done. You need to create a structure in your pages directory like this.

```
- pages
  - categories
    - [categoryId]
      - articles
        - [articleId].js
```

In `[articleId].js` you will have access to `params.categoryId` and `params.articleId`.

If you want to show an article list page for `/categories/:categoryId/articles` you can achieve that by creating a `index.js` file in the `articles` folder. Similarly if you want to show a list of `categories` you can create an `index.js` file in `categories` folder For example,

```
- pages
  - categories
    - index.js   // to show a list of categories
    - [categoryId]
      - articles
        - index.js // to show list of articles for a specific category
        - [articleId].js
```

To summarize

- `/categories` will show `NextPage` component in `pages/categories/index.js`.
- `/categories/:categoryId/articles` will show `NextPage` component in `pages/categories/[categoryId]/articles/index.js`
- `categories/:categoryId/articles/:articlesId` will show the `NextPage` component in `pages/categories/[categoryId]/articles/[articleId].js`

Comment: Awesome!! Because I had my routes in a `:id` format, the only thing I had to do is change the directory from `[id]` to `:id` and it works. Thank you!

Comment: please what version of Nexjs are you guys using? It doesn't work for me. I get a 404.

Comment: @Sofiane That's the core routing logic and to my knowledge should work in any version of `next`, unless you are working with a very old version which had some issues with routing at some point. Please consider posting a question with detailed information, so someone may be able to help with the issue you are having in your case.

Comment: @Sofiane I tried everything and had the same issue, but then I realized I didn't add import { useRouter } from 'next/router'; in those new pages. Check this example repo for all the folder and code stuff: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/tree/canary/examples/dynamic-routing

Comment: @subashMahapatra So If you have index.js inside [categoryId], will that serve ```categories/:categoryId/``` ?